# Boost DFS back_edge

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to find all edges that are part of any cycle in a undirected Graph. Using Boost's [depth_first_search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html) and my understanding of [back edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search), I don't see why the `back_edge` method is called for both edges in the sample Graph which doesn't contain any cycles.

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property, property<edge_weight_t, int> > Graph;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;

class MyVisitor : public default_dfs_visitor {
    public: void back_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        // should only be called when cycle found, right?
        cerr << "back_edge " << e << endl;
        return;
    }
};

int main() {
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);

    MyVisitor vis;
    depth_first_search(g, visitor(vis));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your graph is undirected, any tree edge is also a back edge. The [documentation for DFSVisitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/DFSVisitor.html) doesn't fail to mention this.

> For an undirected graph there is some ambiguity between tree edges and back edges since the edge (u,v) and (v,u) are the same edge, but both the `tree_edge()` and `back_edge()` functions will be invoked.
>
> One way to resolve this ambiguity is to record the tree edges, and then disregard the back-edges that are already marked as tree edges. An easy way to record tree edges is to record predecessors at the tree_edge event point.

Implementing this in the most straightforward manner: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6500c7b4b8058c2)**

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

namespace {
    using namespace boost;

    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property, property<edge_weight_t, int> > Graph;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    typedef std::set<Edge> EdgeSet;
}

struct MyVisitor : default_dfs_visitor {
    MyVisitor(EdgeSet& tree_edges) : tree_edges(tree_edges) {}

    void tree_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        std::cerr << "tree_edge " << e << std::endl;
        tree_edges.insert(e);
    }
    void back_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        if (tree_edges.find(e) == tree_edges.end())
            std::cerr << "back_edge " << e << std::endl;
    }

  private: 
    EdgeSet& tree_edges;
};

int main() {
    Graph g;
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(0, 2, g);

    std::set<Edge> tree_edges;
    MyVisitor vis(tree_edges);

    depth_first_search(g, visitor(vis));
}
```

Comment: How in this example we can `record_predecessor` on_back_edge() event?

Comment: @Bruce I think it's more useful to post that as a new question

Comment: I made this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419307/recording-predecessors-in-a-dfs-search-in-an-undirected-graph